# Android multiple sound for notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Am trying to produce two type of custom notification sound by adding .wav file in raw folder, when notification like job comes it produce job related notification sound in other case if notification like message comes it produce message related notification sound.

I set channel if for get the notification in Higher end device,but after creating the channel id am getting same notification sound when a notification comes based on which type of notification comes first.

**onMessageReceived**

```
    String sound = data.get("sound");
    Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + sound);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIconId())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(messageBody));

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O && notificationManager != null) {
        int importance = android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_MESSAGE, importance);
        mChannel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(messageId, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

**Manifest**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create two notification channels, each channel for each sound and assign the ID of the channels depending on the sound you want to reproduce.
It is explained in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) that once a channel is created it cannot be modified.